# Split speech audio on pause between words in Ruby

Tags: ruby, audio, rubygems, audio-recording

I have a short audio file that that I need to split into many files, one file for each word. For example, my input audio file could contain, "Hello, my name is Todd" which I would need to split into 5 audio files  "Hello", "my", "name", "is", "Todd" based on the pause between words.

I am hoping not to reinvent the wheel and code something from scratch. Which gem or tool can do this? I'm coming up empty so far.

Comment: If you want advice on finding an already-written library for a task, then Stack Overflow is not best place (that type of question is off topic). Please try softwarerecs.stackexchange.com - take a look at their "how to ask" first to get best chance of success.

Answer (score -1):

I created a VB.NET GUI app to split audio files both by silence & time duration simultaneously . It utilizes a command tool found on git-hub called "wavsilence" as well as "s0x". You could set time to 0-0.3 (seconds so it would split at the slightest pause between words). While probably not perfect this is as close as you will find. I too came up empty handed. I created this tool specifically to chapter and split spoken audio. I also have a command line batch version I wrote. Just make sure that the audio is stereo .WAV format (1411kbs).

1. Get wavesilence.exe and sox.exe and create environment variables so you can access them through the command line.
2. Put all the audio files you would like to split into the same folder (stereo wav audio only | foobar is a free converter).
3. Backup original audio files (so you can play with the split settings without destroying the audio)
4. Create and run the batch file > point it to the folder of audio and hit ENTER

gist.github.c0m/Nabspot/671188ed89dcd648a577 <-- my batch command

https://github.com/DOSx86/wavsilence

Download sox from SoX - Sound eXchange

If by chance you find this works well, I have a GUI available for free. I plan to release the GUI Application later this year. Screenshots can be found here.

[image]

"Audiobook Ninja" - Split hours of audio by duration & silence, Split hours of audio into CD sized playlists folders while renaming the audio files by disc and track number... yadda yadda. I made it for work, and this saves me dozens of hours on a weekly basis. I hope it can help you.